# Converting the comma separated values in a cell to different rows by duplicating the other column contents into every row Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-preprocessing

I have a dataset

```
Name    Type        Cluster      Value
ABC     AA,BB       AZ,YZ        15
LMN     CC,DD,EE    LM,LM,LM     20
```

with many other columns.

I want to convert it to a dataframe like:

```
Name    Type        Cluster     Value    TypeSubset    ClusterSubset
ABC     AA, BB      AZ, YZ       15       AA            AZ 
ABC     AA, BB      AZ, YZ       15       BB            YZ
LMN     CC,DD,EE    LM,LM,LM     20       CC            LM
LMN     CC,DD,EE    LM,LM,LM     20       DD            LM 
LMN     CC,DD,EE    LM,LM,LM     20       EE            LM
```

The dataframe can have many columns. But the Number of elements in `Type` and `Cluster` will be same. I just want them separated into different rows and duplicate all the other columns.

How can I do it in python.

I tried

````
df.set_index(['Type','Cluster'])
   .apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.split(',').explode())
   .reset_index())  ```

Not getting the desired result.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assign` new columns and `explode` in parallel.

```
(df.assign(TypeSubset=df['Type'].str.split(','),
           ClusterSubset=df['Cluster'].str.split(',')
           )
   .explode(['TypeSubset', 'ClusterSubset'])
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped immensely. I only needed to split out one column that had CSV's, i just removed any reference to the second column above and all is working!